# Android - RecyclerView get variable in ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This is how I get a view from `ViewHolder` and set a value in it in the Activity:

```
val viewHolder = recyclerViewMemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos) as RecyclerView.ViewHolder
viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.text = "99"
```

but is there a way I could get a variable from the holder?

Comment: You dont want to do this as the views get recycled, what you should do is update you dataset for the recyclerview and call notifyDatasetChanged on your adapter or even better is to call the more specific notify changes like notifyItemChanged

Comment: I would only use this for visible items so there wouldn't be any problems. I need access to the variables userPaused and userPlay to control videoView inside RecyclerView ScrollListener. It's a bit too much to explain but I really need those variables

Answer (score 0):

You must cast ViewHolder type exactly so the RecyclerView.ViewHolder doesn't contain `memeCommentsCount`.

I assume that we have a ViewHolder with the name `ActualViewHolder` and `ItemForVisibleBinding` contains the `memeCommentsCount` text view:

```
class ActualViewHolder(val binding: ItemForVisibleBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

In your Activity:

```
val viewHolder = recyclerViewMemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos) as? ActualViewHolder
viewHolder?.binding?.memeCommentsCount?.text = "99"
```

If you make sure that the RecyclerView is only one ActualViewHolder type then you can use `as` instead `as?`.

Comment: But how do I get variables that are set inside onBindViewHolder in activity?